# What should we use for offline-first with Flutter and Yii2?

Tags: database, flutter, yii2, offline

We wanna create an app that is offline-fist. We're trying to use or create an auto sync database that allows work offline with app. Our client is Flutter and our back-end is Yii2. What is the best solution?

Comment: seeking recommendations is a general opinion based "question" which is Off Topics for SoF.

Answer (score 5):

I have developed multiple offline sync applications. I can not tell you about the backend much but I can tell you about the Flutter.

For storing data on your device there are multiple plugins you can use.

1. [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)-: It works well in android and ios.
2. [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)-: If you want to support all the platforms then you use shared preferences but there might be some security issues here.

For Auto-sync
You can use the internet checker and sync your database with live.

1. [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus)-: Works well but sometimes it does not trigger the callback for connectivity. (work well for all the platforms.)

Note-: This plugin does not give you if the internet is working or not.

2. [internet_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker)-: work well in all cases and also provides if the internet is actually working or not.

If you want to sync when the app is in the background then you may need to use

- [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus)

Happy Coding ;)

Comment: Thank you, Just one more question... There isn't a protocol or any package to auto sync?

Comment: No There is no package available I tried searching. If you find let me know, please.